# Haml: Append class if condition is true in Haml

Tags: ruby, haml

If `post.published?`

```
.post
  / Post stuff
```

Otherwise

```
.post.gray
  / Post stuff
```

I've implemented this with rails helper and it seems ugly.

```
= content_tag :div, :class => "post" + (" gray" unless post.published?).to_s do
  / Post stuff
```

Second variant:

```
= content_tag :div, :class => "post" + (post.published? ? "" : " gray") do
  / Post stuff
```

Is there a more simple and haml-specific way?

UPD. Haml-specific, but still not simple:

```
%div{:class => "post" + (" gray" unless post.published?).to_s}
  / Post stuff
```

Answer (score 336, accepted):

```
.post{:class => ("gray" unless post.published?)}
```

Comment: just a side note for multiple conditions
` {class: [('class1' unless condition1), ('class2' if condition2)]} ` .. etc

Comment: More succinct for multiple conditions: `{ class:[ (:class1 if cond1), (:class2 if cond2) ] }`

Comment: Note: the parentheses are required or you will get ruby syntax error.

Comment: Updated json-style notation: ```.post{class: ("gray" unless post.published?)}```

Answer (score 22):

```
- classes = ["post", ("gray" unless post.published?)]
= content_tag :div, class: classes do
  /Post stuff
```

---

```
def post_tag post, &block
  classes = ["post", ("gray" unless post.published?)]
  content_tag :div, class: classes, &block
end

= post_tag post
  /Post stuff
```

Comment: Not so concise, but looks better than other ways if put into a helper.

Comment: This works well - I noticed that you don't need the `.compact.join(" ")` though. You can simply do `:class => ["post active", ("gray" unless post.published?)]`

Answer (score 15):

Really the best thing is to put it into a helper.

```
%div{ :class => published_class(post) }

#some_helper.rb

def published_class(post)
  "post #{post.published? ? '' : 'gray'}"
end
```

Comment: I've put this in my helper file, but my app tells me, that there is no "post" variable.

Comment: fyi: if you only want to include a class in a certain case and nothing in other cases you can just set `nil` and the attribute will not be set, instead of setting `class=""`

Answer (score 14):

HAML has a nice built in way to handle this:

```
.post{class: [!post.published? && "gray"] }
```

The way that this works is that the conditional gets evaluated and if true, the string gets included in the classes, if not it won't be included.

Answer (score 6):

Updated Ruby syntax:

```
.post{class: ("gray" unless post.published?)}
```