# Neat way to conditionally test whether to add a class in HAML template

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra, haml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Append class if condition is true in Haml (with Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453560/append-class-if-condition-is-true-in-haml-with-rails)

I'm using a template that allows you to mark a list item as `current` (using `class=current`), highlighting it in a nav bar.

In HAML, this looks like:

```
%li.current
  Menu item A
%li
  Menu item B
%li
  Menu item C
```

I have this code in a Sinatra view and want to programmatically add the `class=current`, depending on a parameter to the view.

**How do I do this in the neatest way possible?**

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
  - if section == "pages"
    %li.current
      %a{:href => "#pages"} Pages
  - else
    %li
      %a{:href => "#pages"} Pages
```

Which feels too verbose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can inline the conditional to determine if the class is needed for the %li

```
%li{ :class => ('current' if section == "pages") }
  %a{ :href => "#pages" } Pages
```

Comment: how can you use multiple Ifs for different classes per element with haml?

Comment: Ideally you would not cram all the conditionals inline, it will be ugly and difficult to read. Instead, build the string of class names before and pass it into the haml tag.

Answer (score 3):

If `section` can be another string rather than `"pages"`, you should use something like [**mguymon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272477/mguymon) answered. But if it can only be `nil`, `false` or `"pages"` this code is more succinct:

```
%li{ class:section && 'current' }
  %a{ :href => "#pages" } Pages
```

This use the principle that HAML omit `nil` or `false` attributes and every object in Ruby is evalueted as `true`, except: `false` and `nil`.

So, if `section` is different than `nil` or `false`, then `section && 'current'`  outputs `'current'` else it outputs `false` omitting the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks @waldyr-ar, this is useful also :)

Comment: @DanielMay You're welcome! We're here for that! :)