# Expressing conditional HAML possibly with ternary operator

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Trying to come up with a more compact way of expressing this conditional in HAML and Ruby, perhaps with a ternary operator:

```
- if @page.nil?
  %br (nothing yet)
- else
  %br #{@page.name}
```

(looking for similar approach as per [Neat way to conditionally test whether to add a class in HAML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312052/neat-way-to-conditionally-test-whether-to-add-a-class-in-haml-template))

Your help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you have makes the text a child of the `<br>` element; that is not desirable. What you really meant, I think, was:

```
%br
- if @page.nil?
  (nothing yet)
- else
  #{@page.name}
```

For this you can simply do:

```
%br
#{@page.nil? ? "(nothing yet)" : @page.name}
```

Or

```
%br
= @page.nil? ? "(nothing yet)" : @page.name
```

Or simply:

```
<br>#{@page ? @page.name : "(nothing yet)"}
```

However, personally I would 'fix' this in the controller so that you always have a `@page`, with something like:

```
unless @page
  @page = Page.new( name:"(nothing yet)", … )
end
```

With this you can stub out what a new/empty/nothing page looks like and let your view treat it like any other. Your `@page` still won't have a `@page.id`, so you can use that for tests to decide if you are creating a new item or editing an existing one.

This is how I handle all my forms that may be used to create or edit an item: provide defaults by creating (but not adding to the database) an item with the default values.

*Aside: You're creating a `<br>` which is [almost never a good idea](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#badBR), and you're creating it with Haml which  [should not be used for content markup](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/). You might step back and think about what you're doing.*

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
%br
= @page.try(:name)
```

Comment: -1 This usage of [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) is Rails, not Sinatra. Further, it does not have the "(nothing yet)" text the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed in a string
assuming `- order_count = 12`:

`%h5= Ordered #{ order_count == 1 ? "1 item" : "#{order_count} items" } for this session`

Answer (score -1):

```
%br = @page ? (nothing yet) : #{@page.name}
```

Comment: -1 because: this creates content as a child of `<br>`; the logic is backwards; you are treating Ruby code mode like it is text mode. The 'correct' form to fix the latter two would be `%br= @page ? @page.name : "(nothing yet)"`…but this still creates `<br>foo</br>`. See my answer.