# rails : how to conditionally assign tag in haml

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'd like to add same content but assign a different tag in haml for the sake of SEO.
More specifically, I want the header to be `<h1>` in `PostsController#index` but to be `<p>` on other pages so I try to use

```
-if current_page?(controller: 'top', action: 'index') ? %h2 , %h3
```

but it doesn't work and I think the wrong part in `%h2` `%h3` part.

Comment: the ternary does not need a leading `if` otherwise this is interpreted as `if(if(current_page?(controller: 'top', action: 'index')) then %h2 else %h3)` which in turn just evaluates to what is essentially `if(true)`. Additionally ternary syntax is `condition ? true_value : false_value` Note (**`:`** not comma). I am not a haml expert but [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331309/1978251) should get you the rest of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with HAML but perhaps this?

```
- if current_page?(controller: 'top', action: 'index')
  %h2= some_variable_or_text
- else 
  %p= some_variable_or_text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`haml_tag` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method), something like this:

```
- haml_tag current_page?(controller: 'top', action: 'index') ? :h2 : :h3 do
  Content here.
```

Note that the helper arguments are *symbols*, using `:` not `%`.