# Conditional class in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this html

```
  <tr <% if ap.overdue? %>class = "overdue"<% end %> >
    <td><%= ap.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to ap.affiliate.title, superadmin_affiliate_path(ap.affiliate) %></td>
  </tr>
```

How do I code the equivalent in HAML?
In particular the first line, which assigns a class only if the `if` condition is true.

Comment: http://html2haml.heroku.com/ you can use this website very helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append class if condition is true in Haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453560/append-class-if-condition-is-true-in-haml)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this

```
%tr{ :class => ("overdue" if ap.overdue?) }
```

Comment: If you have classes that you always need and one or more variable classes, you can either use a variable (i.e. class: @some_var) or string interpolation with a ternary (i.e. class: "some-class #{ap.overdue? ? "overdue" : ""}")

Answer (score 6):

HAML has a nice built in way to handle this:

```
%tr{ class: [ap.overdue? && 'overdue'] }
```

The way that this works is that the conditional gets evaluated and if true, the string gets included in the classes, if not it won't be included.