# how to add a class to a conditional in HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

Ok, I have this line in my file which is in HAML

```
- unless @place.blank?
```

I **need** to add a class to it, regardless of the condition.

I've tried doing this:

```
- {:class => ("extra_middle" unless place.blank?)}
```

That doesn't work. I've tried other variations to no avail.

**EDIT**

Please keep in mind that there is a dash which in HAML means do not render unless not blank, right?

**EDIT 2**

To explain a bit more, the class I'm trying to add is meant to hide that specific part unless someone clicks on a link which will then show it ...

So, the class is regardless of result of place being blank or not ...

Comment: Can you share some more code ?/

Comment: What is the error? I am seeing your is right as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453560/append-class-if-condition-is-true-in-haml-with-rails)

Comment: show some more code.........

Comment: You are adding `CSS` class to a `HTML` element right? Where is that HTML element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call me stupid here, but could you not just put the -unless place.blank? inside a div

```
 .extra_middle
    -unless place.blank?
      .Whatever else you need
```

Comment: not at all. I totally forgot the KISS principle. So, clearly, I'm the stupid one here. Your answer worked.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a ternary operation, e.g.:

```
%div{ class: (place.blank? ? nil : 'extra_middle') }
```

... or move into a helper, should it become any more complex than that.

Comment: that doesn't work. I got this error: ` syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end :class => place.blank? ? nil : 'extra_middle'` ... I'm guessing it's not working due to the dash in the beginning of the line? I've tried it without the the line, and this is what I got: `Invalid filter name ":class => place.blank? ? nil : 'extra_middle'".`

Comment: I've added a further clarification to the post regarding what I'm trying to do with the class. Hope it helps.

Comment: Expanded the example, so it works as is when you paste it. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. I just tried it. It doesn't work. This is the error I got: `unknown type of %string %div{ class: (place.blank? ? nil : 'extra_middle') } `

Comment: btw, if I'm reading your line correctly, it postulates that the css class will render if the place is blank, correct?

Comment: that's not what I'm trying to do at all. I'm trying to have the css class render regardless of the output of the condition.